# How do I make a delay in the printing of each letter in my code?

Tags: python, import, delay

I want to put a delay in between each of the characters (e.g. w,e,l,c,o,m,e) with as few imports as possible.

```
import sys

starter_line = ('Welcome to... ')
starter = []
for x in range(len(starter_line)):
        y = starter_line[x-1:x]
        starter.append(y)
print("".join(starter))
```

I tries using the sleep and time modules but it just gave me an error.

Comment: Using `sleep` (and a loop!) is probably the best way to introduce a delay between characters. Show us what you tried (and the error you received).

Comment: Please edit your post with the error you encountered with the time module

Answer (score 0):

```
import time`
text = 'Welcome to... '
x = ''
for characters in text:
    x += characters
    print(x)
    time.sleep(0.3) # 300 milliseconds
```

well, i dont know where you're trying to do this.

But if you trying make this on python screen (Run or Debug)

Output:

```
W
We
Wel
Welc
Welco
Welcom
Welcome
Welcome 
Welcome t
Welcome to
Welcome to.
Welcome to..
Welcome to...
Welcome to...
```

But if you trying make this on "terminal"

```
import time
import os

text = 'Welcome to... '
x = ''
for characters in text:
    x += characters
    print(x)
    time.sleep(0.3) # 300 milliseconds
    os.system('cls||clear') #this thing will clear your terminal screen
```

Output:

```
Welcome to...
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking for is really unclear, but here is a working version of what I believe you were asking for. This code splits the string into a list with each character separate, it then iterates over the list printing the current letter, and then it waits 1 second before doing it again. The reason time.sleep () wasn't working was because you didn't import the time library.

```
import time

starter_line = ('Welcome to... ')

for i in range(len(list(starter_line))):
    print(list(starter_line)[i])
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

It would be really great if you could write a clearer description of what you want since I don't know if you want to add "," between all characters or if you want a time delay like the code I sent.

Comment: I apologise for the unclear question but I meant that I would like each letter printed out with delay in the same line.